# Graphviz dot set aspect ratio(16:9, 4:3 etc)

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

Is there a way to setup the aspect ratio of a dot graph?
I'm trying to obtain the smallest rectangle that contains the graph and has a specific aspect ratio.

I have been searching for this answer a lot and I could not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass in a numerical value to `ratio`:

```
digraph G{
 ratio=1.3;
 node[shape=point, height=0.02, width=0.01];
 foo->bar;
}
```

Or set the size and pass in one of the options (see more options [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ratio)).

```
digraph G{
 ratio="fill";
 size="4,3!";
 node[shape=point, height=0.02, width=0.01];
 foo->bar;
}
```